# how to install an2linux on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, android, python3

I'll try to install [an2linux](https://github.com/rootkiwi/an2linuxserver#an2linux---server) (**Mirror Android Notifications on Linux Desktop**) on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop and Linux mint PC but i cannot understand how to install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the android app on your phone

Install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt install python3 libnotify4 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 python3-gi openssl git
```

Clone the a2nlinux repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/rootkiwi/an2linuxserver
cd an2linuxserver
```

Make executable and run a2nlinux:

```
chmod +x an2linuxserver.py
./an2linuxserver.py
```

Run it again:

```
./an2linuxserver.py
```

Pair your pc to the phone by wifi or bluetooth

Start an2linux app on android and enable it.

Also enable a2nlinux in the enable applications part of the app

If you choose to connect  via wifi from the phone app, add the server to send notifications to: your_pc_ip with port 46352
and hit the `initiating button`
From ubuntu terminal accept the request

The phone should now be able to send notifications